# Server Network Fails whenever a Client Computer connects to Server

Tags: windows, networking, windows-sbs-2011

I have an IBM x3400 server at a remote site, running SBS 2011 Premium. This is a really remote site in outback Australia, about 3000 kms away from me at present. Yesterday their network went down during the day.

I got them to turn everything off and restart the switch, and was then able to remote into the server (via Teamviewer). The server had "Identifying" next to Network, and said it could not detect network. I restarted server and network came up normally, and i was able to use it remotely with no issue. As soon as a client PC was turned on though, the server NIC started switching between "Network Cable is Disconnected" and then connected, switching rapidly every second or so.

From the client PC, ping failed every few seconds to the server with "Request Timed out" or "Destination Unreachable". Turning off the client, and unplugging and replugging the network cable makes it work again until a client PC is turned on.

The NIC in the server is an INTEL 82574L Gigabit, there are 2, either one will do the same when a client is connected to the network.

The server did install updates yesterday, so I am suspicious that this is the culprit, but in these cases I would normally blame the switch. Trouble is they have a long way to go to get a new switch to try. NIC drivers have not changed since initial install.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got them to get another switch to try and this seems to have resolved the problem.

I'm writing this off as a switch failure, but will update this question in future if I find any other issues now everything is back online.